# Upload Google Drive file to Salesforce attachment

Tags: salesforce, google-apps-script, base64

I have everything working except the actual file is not readable.  I assume it loads since I dont get any errors and the attachment is created.  The "file" needs to be base64 in salesforce so I am assuming my problem is that the blob in Drive is not base64.  The question is, how do I convert the file blob to a base64 format for uploading, and will this actually work.

Relevant Code chunks

```
    var payload =  Utilities.jsonStringify(
      {"Name" : name, //string
       "ParentId" : acctId,  //string
       "OwnerId" : ownerId,  //string
       "body" : content  //base64
      }
    );

    var contentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    var feedUrl = instanceUrl + "/services/data/v23.0/sobjects/Attachment/"
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(feedUrl, { method : "POST", headers : { "Authorization" : "OAuth " + accessToken }, payload : payload, contentType: contentType });

    var feed = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
```

looking at it here it seams the Utilities.jsonStringify() the file would be an issue.  Still need some help making this work though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code snippet below works for me. I re-wrote it a bit to fit my sample. I didn't include an ownerid as I didn't know what to include there. I think the key issue might be that you didn't use `getAs()`. If you got pure Google Doc blob then your browser won't know how to convert that. Notice, how I used application/pdf. I believe you can use a similar MIME type for MS Word as well. Also note that I converted to Base64 using the Utilities API.

```
var myFileId = 'MY_FILE_ID';
var myParendId = 'ACCOUNT_ID';
var myToken = 'USER_TOKEN';

var baseContent = DocsList.getFileById(myFileId).getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();
var base64Content = Utilities.base64Encode(baseContent);

var payload =  Utilities.jsonStringify(
  {"Name" : 'ArunTest.pdf', //string
   "ParentId" : myParendId,  //string
   "body" : base64Content  //base64
  }
);

var options = {
        "method": "post",
        "contentType" : "application/json",
        "payload" : payload,
        "headers" : {
                     "Authorization" : "Bearer " + myToken
                    }
}

var getDataURL = UserProperties.getProperty(baseURLPropertyName) + '/services/data/v26.0/sobjects/Attachment/';
var dataResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(getDataURL,options).getContentText();
```

Comment: Perfect just what I needed.  I was not sure what the starting point was for the blob or how to define that.  The getAs obviously solves that problem.  Salesforce requires an owner id when creating an Attachment record.  For us it is easy, our google users are salesforce users so I can look them up via email address.  Others may not have that option.

Comment: Great. Mark this as accepted so that this will show up as an valuable answer to the next person. I was able to get it working without the OwnerId (perhaps it assumes the person uploading is the owner). Either way, I am glad it worked out for you.